# Convert a List<double> to a DataTable column in C#

Tags: c#, list, datatable

I have 4 lists of doubles, each of them contains whole values of a single column of the datatable.
Say,

```
List<double> ValuesA = new List<double>(){0.1,0.2,0.3};
List<double> ValuesB = new List<double>(){0.4,0.5,0.6};
List<double> ValuesC = new List<double>(){0.7,0.8,0.9};
List<double> ValuesD = new List<double>(){1.1,1.2,1.3};
```

I want a datatable like

```
0.1  0.4  0.7  1.1
0.2  0.5  0.8  1.2
0.3  0.6  0.9  1.3
```

I know there's always a method using for/foreach loop, but are there any 'smarter' way, such as Linq query or sth?

Comment: Whatever "smarter" way would probably start by having a nested `List<List<double>> Values = new List<List<double>>() { ValuesA, ValuesB, ValuesC, ValuesD };`

Comment: With datatable, do you mean the [`DataTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx) class? With 4 columns of doubles?

Comment: @smoksnes yes..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *could*; but you need to consider whether you *should*.

If the problem is as stated in the question, then it's not worth the effort. A simple `for` loop does the job.

If this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and you're actually asking "can I write something that will generically take a collection of lists and turn it into a datatable", then yes, but you're going to have to work harder to do it.

For the scenario you've described, it's not worth the effort. For example, the generic version would need to deal with lists that have different lengths and possible different types.

**Update for edit to question**
Linq iterates over something that is enumerable. You have 4 things that are enumerable, so you'd have to iterate over each of them, which is going to be more effort than the for loop.

Comment: I agree, you need to take the count of rows, columns. I would suggest to use a two dimensional double[][] array. It will be easier to create.

Answer (score 1):

A bit hacky but if you want to avoid  `for` and `foreach` then `Linq` is one way to go

```
//determine the max number of rows in case of the List<decimal> are not all equal length
int rows = new[] { ValuesA.Count, ValuesB.Count, ValuesC.Count, ValuesD.Count, }.Max();

Enumerable.Range(0, rows).Select(x => {
    dt.Rows.Add(ValuesA.ElementAtOrDefault(x),
    ValuesB.ElementAtOrDefault(x),
    ValuesC.ElementAtOrDefault(x),
    ValuesD.ElementAtOrDefault(x));
    return true; }).ToList();
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/WXIwT7

---

If all lists have the same length use `ValuesA.Count`

```
Enumerable.Range(0, ValuesA.Count).Select(x => {dt.Rows.Add(ValuesA[x],ValuesB[x], ValuesC[x],ValuesD[x]);return true;}).ToList();
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/NTIb2O

Comment: How this is "smarter" than a simple for loop? It takes just as many lines and is less readable.

Comment: @Richardissimo basically this are two lines (one line if all `ValueX` are the same length) but yes I would also use `for` in my code because it is better to read

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. That was the intent of my answer but clearly I failed to convey it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Although it is not the 'smarter' way I thought since it's kind of tricky using Enumerable.Range instead of for loop. At least @Richardissimo 's and your anwsers remind me there's no need to work out a 'smarter' method.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the simple code which Converts the 4 list to `DataTable`. However, it works on convention that there would be always **fixed** columns and List items.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Xml;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        List<double> ValuesA = new List<double>(){0.1,0.2,0.3};
        List<double> ValuesB = new List<double>(){0.4,0.5,0.6};
        List<double> ValuesC = new List<double>(){0.7,0.8,0.9};
        List<double> ValuesD = new List<double>(){1.1,1.2,1.3};

        var values = new List<object>();
        values.Add(new { A = ValuesA[0], B = ValuesB[0], C = ValuesC[0], D = ValuesD[0] });
        values.Add(new { A = ValuesA[1], B = ValuesB[1], C = ValuesC[1], D = ValuesD[1] });
        values.Add(new { A = ValuesA[2], B = ValuesB[2], C = ValuesC[2], D = ValuesD[2] });


        var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values);
        //Console.WriteLine(jsonString);


        var dataTable = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(jsonString);


        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}", row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3]));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you under *"smarter"* understand, to have some *"fancy"* code, with LINQ, just remember, that under that codes works some *"ugly"* codes (usually, well I personally think that they are pretty *"beautiful"*), probably importing some external dll's and using unsafe codes. If you don't want to deal with for/foreach loop's directly, just write your custom extension method:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static DataTable GetDataTable(this List<List<double>> vs) //You can even make it Generic
    {
        DataTable result = new DataTable();
        //TODO: Use for/foreach loops here
        return result;
    }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<double> ValuesA = new List<double>(){0.1,0.2,0.3};
    List<double> ValuesB = new List<double>(){0.4,0.5,0.6};
    List<double> ValuesC = new List<double>(){0.7,0.8,0.9};
    List<double> ValuesD = new List<double>(){1.1,1.2,1.3};

    var nlist = new List<List<double>>() { ValuesA, ValuesB, ValuesC, ValuesD };
    DataTable table = nlist.GetDataTable();
}
```